# Proof involving Poisson bracket

Tags: dynamical-systems, physics, mathematical-physics, poisson-geometry

[image]

[image]

Not being able to understand how each term has been simplified to get from the third step to the fourth step. So how did 1/2m become 1/m and {qj,plpl}pk become {qj,pl}plpk and how did k/4 become k/2 and {pk,(qlql)^2}qj become {pk,(qlql)}(qmqm)qj.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: $\epsilon-{ijk}$ is known as the Levi-Civita pseudotensor, also known as a permutation symbol and is a shorthand way to denote the cross product. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol

Comment: Also when they substituted H into the bracket they used identities to get rid of certain terms, for example ${q_i,q_j}=0$, so the squared q term is entirely zero for the first bracket, and the p term in H is zero for the second piece

Comment: Not being able to understand how each term has been simplified to get from the third step to the fourth step. So how did 1/2m become 1/m and {qj,plpl}pk become {qj,pl}plpk and how did k/4 become k/2 and {pk,(qlql)^2}qj become {pk,(qlql)}(qmqm)qj.

Comment: I'll see to typing up a better response when I get home I'm on mobile right now and that would take days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third to fourth line is obtained via the product rule again applied to both pieces: 
$$
 \frac{1}{2m} \epsilon_{ijk} \{ q_j, p_l p_l \} p_k 
= \frac{1}{2m} \epsilon_{ijk} \{ q_j, p_l \} p_l p_k 
+ \frac{1}{2m} \epsilon_{ijk} \{ q_j, p_l \} p_l p_k 
= \frac{1}{m}\epsilon_{ijk}\{q_j, p_l \} p_l p_k
$$
Because both are the same statement it doesn't matter which $p_l$ is outside.
The second piece:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{k}{4} \epsilon_{ijk} \{ p_k, (q_l q_l)^2 \} q_j 
&=&\frac{k}{4} \epsilon_{ijk} \{ p_k, (q_l q_l)(q_m q_m) \} q_j \\
&=&\frac{k}{4}\left( \epsilon_{ijk} \{ p_k, (q_l q_l) \}(q_m q_m) q_j +
\epsilon_{ijk} \{ p_k, (q_m q_m) \}(q_l q_l) q_j
\right) \\
&=& \frac{k}{4}\left( \epsilon_{ijk} \{ p_k, (q_l q_l) \}(q_m q_m) q_j +
\epsilon_{ijk} \{ p_k, (q_l q_l) \}(q_m q_m) q_j
\right) \\
&=&\frac{k}{4}\left( 2\epsilon_{ijk} \{ p_k, (q_l q_l) \}(q_m q_m) q_j
\right) = \frac{k}{2}\epsilon_{ijk} \{ p_k, (q_l q_l) \}(q_m q_m) q_j
\end{eqnarray*}
This last part follows from the product rule and then the fact that the repeated indices are not unique, just switch the l and m indices with each other in the second sum because they are dummy indices.